# Sequelize paranoid delete from multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

i currently have a post table, conversation table and a user table in my database. A conversation about a post can occur between 2 users only.

My problem is when i delete a post, i need to delete all conversations about this post as well.

With the code below, i am able to delete a post from my posts table but in the conversation table it is just deleting the postId from the postId column of the corresponding conversations not the entire row.

```
router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
console.log(req.params);

let { id } = req.params;
Post.findByPk(id).then((post) => {
if (post) {
  return post.setConversations([]).then(() => {
  return post.destroy();
  });
} else {
return Promise.reject();   
}
 })
.then(()=>{
res.status(204).send();
},()=>{
res.status(404).send();
})
});
```

I have also tried using CASCADE but it did not work unfortunately.

```
Post.hasMany(Conversation, { 
foreignKey: "PostId",
// onDelete: 'CASCADE' 
});

Conversation.belongsTo(Post,{
foreignKey: "PostId",
allowNull: false,
// onDelete: 'CASCADE'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work but can someone please tell me if what i am doing is correct.

```
router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
console.log(req.params);

let { id } = req.params;
Post.findByPk(id).then((post) => {
if (post) {
  Promise.all([
post.destroy(),
Conversation.destroy({where:{PostId:req.params.id}})
]).then(() => {
    res.status(204).send();
  }),
} else {
  res.status(404).send();
}
});
});
```